# NX monorepo testing with jest: "SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'" for local lib

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, monorepo

We have recently moved a project with nestJS and React into a Nx Monorepo.

We have converted some parts into libs so we can reuse them easily. This all works nice except when testing. When I run `npx nx run-many --all --target=test` I get some errors:

```
           ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,jest){export * from './lib/web-types';
                                                                                             ^^^^^^

           SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
```

I have seen and tried out all the variations I see of this problem and its solutions, but it seems they fix the issue when using 3rd party libs such as lodash etc. Here it is just a lib we write in our project.

It seems to me that it should be something very silly and simple, but I can not find a solution.

Comment: I have similar problem. Any solution?

Comment: Not yet. I have had to work on some more pressing stuff. Will get back to this one though. But as of yet, no solution from me.